# file_get_contents hangs

Tags: php, google-maps

I am using Google GeoCoding services.
I have a PHP application which calls the Google Maps API, and receives JSON data.
The function which calls Google Maps host hangs until it times out, but only when I push to Godaddy Virtual Private server.

I have already ssh'd into the server and edited php.ini
I changed "safe mode" to "off"

I get this error message:

> Message:
>   file_get_contents(http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=xYxY&sensor=false):
>   failed to open stream: Connection timed out

This works fine in my WAMP server but fails on live server. Any ideas why?

Comment: Google may be firewall-ed in Ur live server

Comment: Call your ISP and ask them. That is easiest way. @Sergey is right, this is likely a firewall issue. Many providers don't allow these type of connections.

Comment: Do you get any other info if you try to use `wget` to get the page? Command is: `wget http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=xYxY&sensor=false`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found the answer.  What has been a week, now? I hope others find this solution.  The virtual dedicated servers from GoDaddy are ipv6 enabled, but google maps API is having none of that. So tell Curl to force v4 request, like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
```

credit is due in part to a blog where I found this information:

http://www.businesscorner.co.uk/disable-ipv6-in-curl-and-php/

Comment: Wonderful. I found several bug reports regarding this issue, but you're the first one to actually give a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than just disabling IPv6, you can try to connect over one IP version and then swap to the other if the first attempt fails. This makes your implementation more robust to temporary routing issues on your and the remote end.

You can get this behavior in `file_get_contents()` by binding the connection to an interface with either inet6 or inet, and then try the other address family if the first attempt returns FAIL. I wrote up [how to make `file_get_contents()` more routing-robust and dual-stack](https://www.slightfuture.com/webdev/php-file-contents-dual-stack) for anyone that is interested. I also shows you how to force connections to use IPv4 or IPv6 if you prefer to go down that route.

Answer (score -1):

Use curl for getting external data. Many shared servers prevent use of file_get_contents for external data (http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) due to security risks.

Plenty of curl examples online.

Comment: started with curl. after hours of frustration switched to file_get_contents. Now Im back to curl.  But problem remains. Using curl OR file_get_contents() I can load data from other servers.  I cannot call Google Maps API. The process times for max time on my Virtual dedicated server (120 seconds). WOrkds instantly on my local machine, works instantly with other test url. Just Google maps hangs.

Comment: OK - my answer's not the solution then - and I'll delete shortly. It will be either a GoDaddy firewall/routing issue, or google actively blocking calls - although I would have thought would both instantly time-out. Sorry for the bum steer (but still suggest you stay with curl for future developement).

Comment: Thanks Robbie, I've moved back to CuRL I think you're right about it being the better approach.

Answer (score -2):

Check your network. Google doesn't block such request.

Check [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/NVu68l).